# MVC3 and Twitter Bootstrap TypeAhead without plugin

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead

I have gotten TypeAhead to work properly with static data and am able to call my controller function properly and get data but it is either A: Not parsing the data properly or B: The TypeAhead is not set up correctly.

JavaScript :

```
<input type="text" id="itemSearch" data-provide="typeahead" value="@ViewBag.Item" name="itemSearch"/>




    $('#itemSearch').typeahead({
    source: function (query, process) {
        parts = [];
        map = {};

        $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("MakePartsArray")',
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                data: {query: query},
                success: function (data) {
                                $.each(data, function (i, part) {
                                map[part.description] = part;
                                parts.push(part.description);
                            });

                            typeahead.process(parts);
                }
            });
    },
    updater: function (item) {
        selectedPart = map[item].itemNumber;
        return item;
    },
    matcher: function (item) {
        if (item.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.query.trim().toLowerCase()) != -1) {
            return true;
        }
    },
    sorter: function (items) {
        return items.sort();
    },
    highlighter: function (item) {
        var regex = new RegExp('(' + this.query + ')', 'gi');
        return item.replace(regex, "<strong>$1</strong>");
    }
});
```

Controller :

```
    public ActionResult MakePartsArray(string query)
    {
        var possibleItem = query.ToLower();
        var allItems = Db.PartInventorys.Where(l => l.ItemNumber.Contains(possibleItem)).Select(x => new { itemNumber = x.ItemNumber, description = x.Description });
        return new JsonResult
        {
            ContentType = "text/plain",
            Data = new { query, total = allItems.Count(), suggestions = allItems.Select(p => p.itemNumber).ToArray(), matches = allItems, },
            JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
        };
    }
```

In my controller I see the data being retrieved correctly and it appears to parse properly but nothing is showing up for my TypeAhead.

Any idea on how to verify exactly where the breakdown is occurring or does anyone see direct fault in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in the ajax call-

```
   $.ajax({
           url: '@Url.Action("MakePartsArray")',
           dataType: "json",
           type: "POST",
           data: {query: query},
           success: function (data) {
               $.each(data.matches, function (i, part) {
                   var composedInfo = part.description + ' (' + part.itemNumber + ')';
                   map[composedInfo] = part;
                   parts.push(composedInfo);
                });

                process(parts);
           }
       });
```

and in the controller on the return type

```
  return new JsonResult
        {
            ContentType = "application/json",
            Data = new { query, total = allItems.Count(), suggestions = allItems.Select(p => p.itemNumber).ToArray(), matches = allItems },
            JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
        };
```

Comment: can you elaborate the problem in the ajax call?

Comment: On success I was not handling the returned Json properly.  If you insert the answer over top of the code in the question it should work.  Actually you also need to define a variable 'selectedPart' to reference whatever you select and delete the value='@ViewBag.Item' in the input box.